# In RUBY, discover if at least one fine in a folder is linked - has symbolik link - to a specific file

Tags: ruby, file, symlink

I need to check if in a folder, at least one fine is linked (symbolik link) to a specific file. If yes, print string "OK", otherwhise "NO"

```
destination_folder="/home/my_folder"
symbolik_link="script.rb"
```

es) "ls -al" of the folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test1.rb -> ../test/calculator.rb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test2.rb -> ../test/sum.rb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test3.rb -> ../test/test.rb
```

Result: "NO"

es) "ls -al" of the folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test1.rb -> ../test/calculator.rb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test2.rb -> ../test/sum.rb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 test test   49 Nov 27 16:09 ruby_test3.rb -> ../test/script.rb
```

Result: "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missunderstood your question at first. Here's a new try.

To begin with, you can check if a file is a symlink with `File.symlink?(file)`.

I'm going to assume that it's enough that the symlink points to the same path as the original file.

To "follow" a symlink, you can use `Pathname#realpath`.

Like so:

```
require 'pathname'

wanted_file_path = File.expand_path('./lib/foo.rb')
directory = Dir.new('.')
found = directory.entries.any? do |entry|
  if File.symlink?(entry)
    Pathname.new(entry).realpath.to_s == wanted_file_path
  end
end

if found
  puts "Found a matching symlink"
else
  puts "No matching symlink found"
end
```